# Subdomains in IIS 10 Windows Server 2022

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, dns, wildcard-subdomain

i need some help.

Im working on a ASP.NET system works on IIS windows server 2022

I pay for windows server 2022 VPS (opencloud.cl), buy my principal domain (briz.cl) and SSL basic certification (SSL.com).

The idea is that the system will be used by simultaneous clients, and my questions are:

-What is the easiest form for apply various sites in IIS with different hostnames?? example:
client 1 -> client1.briz.cl (site1 in IIS)
client 2 -> client2.briz.cl (site2 in IIS)

-I need one SSL certificate for each "subdomain" i created? Or is possible use the same ssl (briz.cl) for all sites??

Thanks for all!

---

I try to configure wildcard IIS for my domains:

principal site http://*:80 and https://*:443 with hostname binding *.briz.cl

and other sites with differentes hostname site1.briz.cl, site2.briz.cl.

I created a primary zone (briz.cl) on Windows Server DNS, and differents A records nn hosts file like site1.briz.cl <Server_IP>, but this hostnames cant accesibles from internet (others red) any case.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, so does not belong here. You should buy a good book or hire a consultant to get started, instead of buying blindly and hope everything just works.

Answer (score 0):

> I need one SSL certificate for each "subdomain" i created? Or is possible use the same ssl (briz.cl) for all sites??

Wildcard SSL certificates can support the protection of a domain name and all subdomains at the same level under this domain name, without limiting the number of subdomains at this level. For example, a `*.briz.cl` certificate will cover `site1.briz.cl`, `site2.briz.cl`, etc., but would not cover `*.*.briz.cl`, such as `www.site.briz.cl`, because they are at different level.

> but this hostnames cant accesibles from internet (others red) any case.

After adding the A record, it may take a while for the DNS system to update the DNS cache for the new DNS record to take effect. You may need to wait a while before trying to access your subdomain. You can use an online DNS lookup tool to verify that your DNS is configured correctly. Also, you need to make sure your server port is not blocking incoming traffic on ports 80 and 443.